# Sending a web page as HTML mail from Perl

Tags: html, perl, email, cpan

Anyone knows what happened to the very useful **HTML::Mail** package which used to be on CPAN? The package gave you the possibility of sending web pages as HTML attachment, with various options for inlining embedded content such as css and images. The package integrated nicely with whatever mail infrastructure your server had (postfix, sendmail,...).

I am moving a big old Perl driven website from Fedora into AWS and Ubuntu, and HTML::Mail is the only package I am not able to find. I can't seem to find any single substitute either, so any pointers are welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It still seems to [be there](https://metacpan.org/release/PLANK/HTML-Mail-0.11). But the fact that the module name is in red (which means it's unindexed for some reason) and the module hasn't been updated since 2008 would make me wary of using it.

There's a [review of it](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/HTML-Mail) on CPAN Ratings which says:

> This module is like MIME::Lite::HTML or Email::MIME::CreateHTML. Like
>   the former, it uses MIME::Lite, and for that reason alone I suggest
>   you avoid it. MIME::Lite is quite buggy, and best avoided in all
>   situations. Investigate, instead, Email::MIME::CreateHTML.

So I'd look at [Email::MIME::CreateHTML](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME::CreateHTML) instead.

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful. Email::MIME::CreateHTML seems to provide everything I need.